# Transaction and DomainService Types

Tags: ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I'm trying to develop enterprise application with asp.net core in microservice with onion arch and I have some question about domain service (my purpose is to specify business implementation place  which is related to transactions and other type of domain service that include business logic):

1. How many types of domain service do we have and where should I implement them?
2. What I understood is application service is for use cases so it means we shouldn't implement real world business logic (like calculation and what ever is related to real world business they should be on domain)
3. I need to manage some transactions that includes some calculation and works with aggregates, where should I place them.

this is how it goes nearly, my project arch:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTbDe.png)